# JavaFX borderpane.setCenter replaces entire scene

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I'm trying to load a FXML into a FXML. The main FXML has a borderpane, and the second contains a VBox. I load both of these with the FXMLLoader. When I try to set the center of the boarderpane, the entire screen gets replaced with the second FXML. Here is the code

```
BorderPane riskAnalysis = new BorderPane((BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("./proposaldevelopment/riskAnalysis.fxml")));
VBox center = new VBox((VBox) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("./proposaldevelopment/openRiskAssessmentVbox.fxml")));
riskAnalysis.setCenter(center);
root = riskAnalysis;

stage.getScene().setRoot(root);
```

Any ideas that could cause this? I also tried making a new label and putting that into the borderpane center with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as

```
BorderPane riskAnalysis = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("./proposaldevelopment/riskAnalysis.fxml"));
VBox center = (VBox) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("./proposaldevelopment/openRiskAssessmentVbox.fxml"));
riskAnalysis.setCenter(center);
stage.getScene().setRoot(riskAnalysis);
```

Comment: this worked. It must have had something to do with me loading it as a new BorderPane/Vbox -Thanks for the help!